# Reading a crosstabs

Tags: spss, descriptive-statistics

I am confused and struggling to read this simple crosstabs.

[image: Crosstabs]

I am trying to create a profile of downloaders. One of the demographics I am looking at is age. Should I be looking at the percentage within Age or percentage within Type of downloader?

For example, Mixed downloaders are most likely to be 18-21 (50%)? Or should it be they are most likely to be 18-21 (68.4%)??

Could someone help explain please

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since we generally treat age as a stratifying variable, we would look at age standardized proportions. That's because, comparing like-to-like in usage habits, we expect great variation in usage between age groups. Indeed we see that. The "% within age" proportions are the values you're after.